# How to install php5.6 in ubuntu 16.04 with php7?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-16.04, php-7, php-5.6, php-ini

I have got a problem, a few months ago I updated ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04, and my php5.6 from LAMP had problems working next to php7, so I removed it. New projects are fine now, but if I am trying to update composer in older projects, console returns error... Content below:

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for simpay/api_client dev-master -> satisfiable by simpay/api_client[dev-master].
    - simpay/api_client dev-master requires ext-curl ^0.0.0 -> the requested PHP extension curl has the wrong version (7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) installed.

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

It will be possible to install php5.6 without any problems? And make alias for example php5? How to do it?

Comment: you may need to compile your desired version from source .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just install php5.6 with apt-get. I got my instructions from [here](https://lornajane.net/posts/2016/php-7-0-and-5-6-on-ubuntu).
Be sure to use ondreij's ppa repository. This way php7.0 and php5.6 are installed side by side as completely separate packages.

I am on a fresh 16.04 install. I installed php7.0 and all needed extensions. Today I installed php5.6 and made aliases to switch back and forth between the two versions. Put this in ~/.bash_aliases and reload it.

```
alias enablephp5.6="sudo ln -s -f /usr/bin/php5.6 /etc/alternatives/php"
alias enablephp7.0="sudo ln -s -f /usr/bin/php7.0 /etc/alternatives/php"
```

So now when running `php` from console or when using `composer install` you can enable the correct version. It works perfectly for me.

If you need additional php5.6 extensions just install them with `sudo apt-get install php5.6-<extension>`.

Comment: best solution! Thanks!!